# How do I dual wield weapons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm not sure how I can equip a weapon in each hand.  Like a dagger/dagger combination, or a sword/dagger combo.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

From your inventory, left click to equip a weapon onto the right hand and right click to equip onto the left hand.

Comment: Left trigger for left and Right trigger for right on Xbox. Same for PS except L2 and R2.

Answer (score 4):

Go to a desired weapon in your inventory, then use your left attack button (PC defaults to right mouse button, consoles use L1) to put it in your left hand, then go to the second weapon and do the same with your right attack button (PC defaults to left mouse button, consoles use R1) for your right hand. You can do it the other way around too.

Note that selecting a two-handed weapon with either hand will replace both weapons, but when you switch back to a one-handed weapon, it will remember if you had a weapon in the other hand and put it back, assuming you still have it.